# Hosting a precompiled WCF REST service in IIS6 - how?

Tags: wcf, iis-6, precompiled

Can anyone provide a repeatable process for hosting a precompiled website or a web application in IIS6 that can be built using aspnet_compiler? I cannot get code to build reliably (works sometimes) with aspnet_compiler without hitting the "cannot load type: global" error. Changing to a website does not help as I can't even get the precompiled site to come up in IIS6. Whether it's a site or an app makes no difference to me so long as it works.

If anyone has some good info or can point me in the right direction, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you develop it as a web application, which will compile the service code into a single DLL. Dropping that DLL into the bin directory and copying the SVC file should work fine.

Comment: The web application approach should work, but I get intermittent issues with aspnet_compiler not being able to load the global.asax (which I admit, shouldn't be in a WCF app anyway and is getting yanked out). I don't have the luxury of building in VS and manually dropping DLLs (which does work), I have to use aspnet_compiler so I can integrate this into build scripts.